# onclick() function is not working with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So yesterday, I added some Jquery code and it worked perfectly. Today I was adding some more for a new part of my website and it did not work. When I tried the code I added yesterday, that stopped working as well. The first thing I do is create a function to get anything from the url that I need. The first 2 inputs are for following users. The first input should send the id variable to the url bar and is retrieved in the php file called follow.php. The second input should do the same thing. Finally the last function is for liking peoples posts. It sends the type of like(like or unlike) to the php file named like.php and is retrieved there. And should post the retrieved data into a div called likes. However, none of which is occurring when the buttons are pressed. Even when I just send an alert to make sure the on click is working, nothing happens either.
Here is my code:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

}

```
$('input#sub').on('click', function(){
    var id = getParameterByName('id');
    $.get('follow.php' , {id: id}, function(data){  
    location.reload();
    });
});

$('input#sub1').on('click', function(){
    var id = getParameterByName('id');
    $.get('unfollow.php' , {id: id}, function(data){
    location.reload();
    });   
});

function doAction(postid , type){
    alert("Works");
    $.post('like.php' , {postid: postid type: type} , function(data){
        $('div#likes').text(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console?

Comment: I'm not getting errors. Nothing happens when you click one of the buttons

Comment: Can you post a complete code example in your question that reproduces the problem please? Otherwise we're forced to guess. A jsFiddle.net example in addition is also usually helpful.

Comment: If you alert id right after the definition does is show anything? You should use $(this) inside the function after the click event...

Comment: This is the code that is supposed to trigger the do action function: <a href="javascript:;" onclick="doAction('<?php echo $s_id; ?>' , 'Like')" id="<?php echo $s_id ?>"><img id="like" src="Social/down.png"/> </a>

Comment: Oh an Masiorama it does not show anything

Comment: No alerts are working at all

Comment: @RyanTobin From what I get you are messing up with jquery and native javascript code, while you should just use jquery built-in shorthands.  Edit your question and sum up all your actual code, then we could start from the entire thing and fix it, hopefully.

Comment: Ok and should i show the code from the php files being accessed?

Comment: @RyanTobin Nope, we can assume that your  $s_id does hold a value. I'll try to write a simple answer right below to explain you what are the basis of the proper way to use jquery and events, hope it helps.

Comment: There's a typo. Is this a copy-paste-error? `{postid: postid type: type} ` --> comma missing between postid and type.

Comment: @peter_the_oak that could have something. Ill fix and see what happens

Comment: I have revised the question

Comment: However the liking part does still not work for some reason

Comment: Well, this is great :-) But I do not understand why this didn't throw an error, as you mentioned. I copied your function `doAction()` to jsbin.com and it showed me several warnings. Is there any `try` block that could swallow the messages?

Comment: No, Not that I know of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to sum things up. I'm gonna change most of your code simply because you don't need all of that, otherwise jQuery wouldn't be helpful at all.

Assuming your caller is this anchor:

```
<a href="#" id="<?php echo $s_id; ?>" class="idsfromdb"><img id="like" src="Social/down.png"/></a>
```

After this you can manipulate the clicked object getting its attributes easily through:

```
$('.idsfromdb').click(function(){
     var id = $(this).prop('id'); 
     var another_id_obj = $('newselector').prop('id');
     // more logic, ajax,... 
});
```

You can attach this kind of functions to every click event and then manipulate the object, call a php file, and so on... I hope I helped you somehow with this.

Comment: is the "youridnumber" supposed to be the php echo that echoes the id retrieved from the database?

Comment: Yes. If it seems a nonsense, since you don't know from the start, you can use a class selector, and then get the id... let me change the answer to explain that.

Comment: So this works, however it only shows the like when you refresh the page any ideas?

Comment: You mean you want to be able to reload the page right after the like?

Comment: Well I know that would be location.reload(); But i would like it to show without the page having to refresh

Comment: If you want to remove the possibility to like again, you just have to manipulate the anchor in the dom right after the successful ajax call... you did something in your question's code... $('div#likes').text(data); ...

Comment: Ok but do you know how to display the like without the page having to refresh. For some reason, it has to refresh

Comment: As I said before, you have to manipulate the dom as you prefer. I don't have a straightforward answer simply because I don't know what is the final result you want. Can you make a visual example?

Comment: Ok. So basically when you click the like button, the page should not have to refresh and the number should go up. As of now I am not worried about the user liking the post more than once

Comment: Then you could simply hide the button: $(id).hide(); and then +1 the counter with something like: var newTotal = $('#wherethetotalnumberisshown').val()++; $('#wherethetotalnumberisshown').val(newTotal);

Comment: or even better: $('#wherethetotalnumberisshown').val( function(i, oldval) {
    return ++oldval;
});

Answer (score 0):

open google developer tools > network and see if request is made and if it has all data you want as request and if there is anything in response.

if there is request with all parameters, you have problem on server side,
if parameters not same that you are trying to send with ajax, than prevent buttons default action, you must prevent it every time when using ajax especially when button submits form.

```
$('input#sub').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //your ajax
}
```